# Unable to compile simple go program using foundationdb

Tags: go, foundationdb

Trying to cross compile on macos arm for linux. My sample project looks like this:
main.go:

```golang
package main

import(
 "github.com/apple/foundationdb/bindings/go/src/fdb"
)


func main() {
        fdb.APIVersion(630)
        fdb.MustOpenDatabase("fdb.cluster")
}
```

go.mod

```
module fdbtest

go 1.19

require github.com/apple/foundationdb/bindings/go v0.0.0-20221026173525-97cc643cef69

require golang.org/x/xerrors v0.0.0-20191204190536-9bdfabe68543 // indirect
```

go.sum

```
github.com/apple/foundationdb/bindings/go v0.0.0-20221026173525-97cc643cef69 h1:vG55CLKOUgyuD15KWMxqRgTPNs8qQfXPtWjYYN5Wai0=
github.com/apple/foundationdb/bindings/go v0.0.0-20221026173525-97cc643cef69/go.mod h1:w63jdZTFCtvdjsUj5yrdKgjxaAD5uXQX6hJ7EaiLFRs=
golang.org/x/xerrors v0.0.0-20191204190536-9bdfabe68543 h1:E7g+9GITq07hpfrRu66IVDexMakfv52eLZ2CXBWiKr4=
golang.org/x/xerrors v0.0.0-20191204190536-9bdfabe68543/go.mod h1:I/5z698sn9Ka8TeJc9MKroUUfqBBauWjQqLJ2OPfmY0=
```

I've installed foundationdb go lang bindings via `go get github.com/apple/foundationdb/bindings/go@6.3.25`

but when I do `env GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build` I get the following errors:

```
 env GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build                                                                                       
# github.com/apple/foundationdb/bindings/go/src/fdb
../../../go/pkg/mod/github.com/apple/foundationdb/bindings/go@v0.0.0-20221026173525-97cc643cef69/src/fdb/keyselector.go:39:10: undefined: KeyConvertible
../../../go/pkg/mod/github.com/apple/foundationdb/bindings/go@v0.0.0-20221026173525-97cc643cef69/src/fdb/snapshot.go:33:3: undefined: transaction
../../../go/pkg/mod/github.com/apple/foundationdb/bindings/go@v0.0.0-20221026173525-97cc643cef69/src/fdb/generated.go:45:9: undefined: NetworkOptions
<...>
../../../go/pkg/mod/github.com/apple/foundationdb/bindings/go@v0.0.0-20221026173525-97cc643cef69/src/fdb/generated.go:94:9: too many errors
```

So it seems that it cannot find any of the types from fdb. Yet the `KeyConvertible` and the `NetworkOptions` (and others) exist in `../../../go/pkg/mod/github.com/apple/foundationdb/bindings/go@v0.0.0-20221026173525-97cc643cef69/src/fdb/fdb.go`

My golang version: `go version go1.19.3 darwin/arm64`
Newer fdb go bindings (7.1.25, 7.1.0) seem to behave the same...

what am I missing here?

Comment: What happens if you don't cross compile? Will that build successfully? Or are you suggesting the tool can't resolve dependencies only during cross compile?

Comment: foundationdb does not yet support and compile on silicon mac at all, so no way to test that

Comment: I get this as of version 7.1.31 as well

Answer (score 0):

If you follow https://github.com/apple/foundationdb/tree/main/bindings/go you can see how to install the package properly.

Answer (score 0):

arm64 architecture installations may be problematic but you should also check some requirements.

In my case with amd64 architecture the default Ubuntu installation for Windows 11 WSL2 was missing some dependencies:

- mono
- libc6
- cmake

After installing the above packages the errors were gone.

See more details at https://forums.foundationdb.org/t/golang-errors-finding-github-com-apple-foundationdb-bindings-go-src-fdb/4133